# can't upload a video by using Twython

Tags: python, api, video, twitter, twython

I've been trying to upload a mp4 video to twitter by using Twython.
But "Upload_video" API returns 400 bad request error.

Below is my code and error message.

- My Python script

```
  moviefile='/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/xx.mp4'

  video=open(moviefile, 'rb')
  response=`api.upload_video(media=video, media_type='video/mp4')`
  api.update_status(status='Hello!!!',media_ids[response['media_id']]
```

- Trace back and Error

```
  File "movie_end.py", line 72, in 
    tweet(moviefile)
  File "movie_end.py", line 26, in tweet
    response = api.upload_video(media=video, media_type='video/mp4')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/endpoints.py", line 201, in upload_video
    return self.post(upload_url, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 268, in post
    return self.request(endpoint, 'POST', params=params, version=version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 258, in request api_call=url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 194, in _request
    retry_after=response.headers.get('X-Rate-Limit-Reset'))
twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 400 (Bad Request), An error occurred processing your request.
```

Is there anyone who succeed upload a video?
There is little about upload_video api.
I used below web page as reference.
https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/advanced_usage.html

Do you find any mistake in my script?

By the way,,,

- I could upload jpeg by using "upload_media" API, so it seems that
  authentication is collect.
- And Movie file was made by using avconv utility. It was converted
  from avi to mp4 file.

Comment: I got it!! My script has no mistake but video file has any problem. I tried to upload the same video file by using web site, error message appeared.

Comment: What was the issue? I'm getting the same